# Is there a faster way to download a list of blobs from a bucket?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to download a list of blobs (>100000) from a bucket on GCP. Each blob contains a small amount of data (<1KB). Right now I am averaging at 20 blobs per seconds which is very slow. I am using the following code:

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('my_bucket')
blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix='foobar/')
result = []
for blob in blobs:
  result.append(blob.download_as_string())
```

Is there a faster way to do that ?

Comment: What language are you using? Python? Which version?

Comment: I use Python 3.6.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about Google Cloud Storage but you could create a `ThreadPoolExecutor` (from module `concurrent.futures`) with a few workers and submit a slice of the blobs to each.

They are particulary suitable for I/O bound tasks such as yours.

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#threadpoolexecutor-example) is well written.